# Access Nuxt plugins in .js files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Let's say that I have a script file, `foo.js`:

```
function doStuff() {
   // how to access store and other plugins here?
}

export default { doStuff }
```

Without passing the calling component as an argument, how can I access things like `app` or installed plugins like `store`, `i18n` in a script file like the one above?

Comment: Please, elaborate why default plugin format doesn't work for you? `export default ({ app, store }) => { /* plugin code */ }`

Comment: @aBiscuit Because the script file is not a plugin

Comment: Where does `doStuff` is expected to be called from? Components, store or other places? This may help to determine better approach of implementation.

Comment: @aBiscuit Sorry for not being clear about that. Mainly from components. I would like to avoid `doStuff(this)`, `doStuff.call(this)` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple ways to call custom function with `this` being a reference to the component it was invoked in.

**1) Using [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics)**

Custom function can be declared as a method and used within component via `this.customMethod`.

`customHelpers.js`

```
const customHelpers = {
  methods: {
    doStuff () {
      // this will be referenced to component it is executed in
    }
  }
}
```

`component.vue`

```
// component.vue
import customHelpers from '~/mixins/customHelpers'
export default {
  mixins: [customHelpers],
  mounted () {
    this.doStuff()
  }
}
```

**2. Using [context injection](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#inject-in-root-amp-context)**

Declare custom plugin:

`plugins/customHelpers.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.prototype.$doStuff = () => { /* stuff happens here */ }
```

And use plugin in `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  ..., // other nuxt options
  plugins: ['~/plugins/customHelpers.js']
}
```

This makes method available inside every component:

```
export default {
  mounted () {
    this.$doStuff()
  }
}
```

**3) Using [combined injection](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject)**

Same as method **2**, but injection will be also accessible inside `fetch`, `asyncData` and inside store modules. Bindings to `this` may vary, since context is not available everywhere.

`plugins/customHelpers.js`

```
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  inject('doStuff', () => { /* stuff happens here */ })
}
```

And use plugin in `nuxt.config.js`

```
export default {
  ..., // other nuxt options
  plugins: ['~/plugins/customHelpers.js']
}
```

Usage example:

```
export default {
  asyncData ({ app }) {
    app.$doStuff()
  }
}
```

Please, refer to [documentation](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/#combined-inject) for more examples.

Comment: Thanks for your examples. Let's say that I don't want to define a plugin or mixin, and simply want to access the store or similar inside `customHelpers.js`. Is that possible?

Comment: Taking a step back.. Generally, what you want to do is to have a function with dynamically bound context. There has to be an access point for context. It can be done right in place of invocation (e.g. doStuff.bind(this), or assigning function directly to component's method, so Vue does binding for you), or it can be done through ways provided by environment you develop in - Nuxt.js in this case, which are listed above. I don't think there would be better options in terms of keeping logic maintainable and predictable.