# How to call plugin method from component inside asyncData in nuxt js

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

component: pages/user/_username.vue

```js
export default {
  async asyncData({ context, route, $twitter }) {
    const userProfile = await $twitter
      .getUserProfile(route.params.username)
      .then((userProfile) => userProfile.data)
    return { userProfile }
  },
}
```

plugin/twitter.server.js

```js
async getUserProfile(username) {
    const userProfiles = await axios
      .get(
        `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=${username}&count=100&tweet_mode=extended`,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + (await this.fetchAccessToken()),
          },
        }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        return res
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
          this.cache.set('accessToken', this.fetchAccessToken())
          return this.getSampleStatuses()
        }
      })
    return userProfiles
  }
```

This code working on only server side rendering. i want to call client side or server side rendering. how to call on client side

Comment: Any one please help me...

Comment: this discussion might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53302905/access-nuxt-plugins-in-js-files

Answer (score -1):

You can access $twitter (assuming you’ve set it up as a plugin) via the root Vue app instance. You access the root Vue app instance via the context, which you have already included in the asyncData call.

Just change:

```
const userProfile = await $twitter
```

To:

```
const userProfile = await context.app.$twitter
```

Comment: When i add your code in our project then show the message  Cannot read property 'app' of undefined

I don't know what is exactly my issue

Comment: You may have left out the message?

Comment: this is error message `Cannot read property 'app' of undefined` my Code working perfect server side but issue on client side only  @nick-dawes